# Why is my variable not being updated?

Tags: c, debugging, embedded

I have defined a variable with an initial value.
When stepping through the code:

- I can see the initial value
- My function changes the value
- When I use the variable later it has the wrong value

What is happening?

<sub>Note: this is intended as a reference question for common problems. If the generic answers here don't help you, post a question **containing your complete, actual code**.</sub>

Comment: I see what you're doing, however you may want to add some reference code to the question for better quality.

Comment: I agree.  While I've experienced this issue many times, it's hard to come up with good examples on the fly.  I plan to continually update this question over time as I encounter better examples than my fabricated ones here.  If anyone can provide better examples, I'll edit the post to reflect them.

Comment: Just use an example from your answer, or even a generic hello world. This is a question that sets the tone for the site. We don't want to invite everyone to start asking code troubleshooting questions w/out providing at least *some* code ;)

Comment: I'll think on this a little before editing.  The problem is that there are so many disparate reasons this could happen, it's hard to come up with a meaningful code snippet to cover multiple cases.  That's why I described the symptoms.  I checked stackoverflow before creating this and there are several questions about specific cases of this, but I wanted this question to be a generic catch-all of things for people to try before posting a their own question.

Comment: If you'd like to make an example "bug" post like this, the best form would be to provide a few answers for what you think "typical" reasons would be.  Bug questions with no context are somewhat hollow -- especially in an environment where people may be using one of a dozen different c compilers!

Answer (score 15):

There are several reasons why a variable might not keep a value.  While some are arcane and difficult to debug, some of the most common reasons include:

**The variable is modified by an interrupt**

```
//---in main()---
unint8_t rxByte = 0;
printf("%d", rxByte);   //prints "0"

//---later in Uart0_Rx_Handler()---
rxByte = U0RXREG;       //rxByte set to (for example) 55

//---later in main()---
printf("%d", rxByte);   //still prints "0"!!!
```

If a variable is modified by an interrupt handler, it needs to be declared *volatile*. Volatile lets the compiler know that the variable could be modified asynchronously and that it shouldn't used a cached copy in a register.

```
//---in main()---
volatile unint8_t rxByte = 0;
printf("%d", rxByte);   //prints "0"

//---later in Uart0_Rx_Handler()---
rxByte = U0RXREG;       //rxByte set to 55

//---later in main()---
printf("%d", rxByte);   //corectly prints 55
```

**Overrunning an array's bounds**

There are no checks in C to prevent you from going beyond the bounds of an array.

```
int array[10];
int my_var = 55;

printf("%d", my_var);   //prints "55"
for(i=0; i<11; i++)   // eleven is one too many indexes for this array
{
  array[i] = i;
}
printf("%d", my_var);   // prints "11"!!!
```

In this case, we go through the loop 11 times, which is one index bigger than the array.  In most compilers, this will result in overwriting variables declared after the array (anywhere on the page, they don't even have to be declared on the next line). This scenario can occur in many different circumstances, including multi-dimensional arrays and stack corruption.

**Forgetting to dereference a pointer**

While trivial, forgetting the asterisk on a pointer when making assignments will not set the variable correctly

```
int* pCount;
pCount = 10;   //forgot the asterisk!!!
printf("%d", *pCount);   //prints ??
```

**Masking a variable with the same name**

Reusing a variable name in an inner scope (like inside an if/for/while block or inside a function) hides a variable with the same name elsewhere.

```
int count = 10;   //count is 10
if(byteRecevied)
{
  int count = U0RXREG;   //count redeclared!!!
  DoSomething(count); 
  printf("%d", count);   //prints "55"
}
printf("%d", count);   //prints "10"
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to add another possible reason to Zack's excellent answer.

**Optimisation**

This one frequently surprises me. A good optimising compiler will notice when two different variables are never used at the same time, and will *optimise the program by giving those variables the same address in memory*. When you are stepping through the code, you may see a variable apparently changing in the watch window. But what's really happening is that the variable that shares its address is being written to.

The other trick the compiler pulls is simply getting rid of a variable that it realises isn't necessary. Sometimes you might be doing the equivalent of this in your code:

```
force_a = mass_a * acceleration_a
force_b = mass_b * acceleration_b
total_force = force_a + force_b
```

The compiler sees that there's no real need for the variables *force_a* and *force_b*, and so changes the code to this:

```
total_force = (mass_a * acceleration_a) + (mass_b * acceleration_b)
```

You'll never see *force_a* and *force_b* being updates, but you'll still be able to add them to the watch window.

When I step through my program, I'm *convinced* that some variable or other has the wrong value in it, but when I let my program run through without stepping, it seems to work. Check that this isn't happening to you.

**Added:**

As Ashish Kulkarni mentioned, you can check this by turning off optimisation.

Comment: Proper use of "volatile" should fix many such optimization issues.  Just warns the compiler that, "yes, this is a real variable and I promise you that this value can change, but you just can't see it."

Comment: Yes. Optimization is one of the main reasons for such behavior. It would help if you would mention in your answer that optimization _can_ be disabled in most IDE's and gcc so that this behaviour might be worked around.